# В каких случаях на практике применять рефлексию, аннотации?

Tags: java, аннотации, рефлексия

Помогите уяснить.

К примеру, одно из частных определений рефлексии говорит: "*Рефлексия* - это инструмент с помощью которого можно узнать всю информацию о классе: имена методов, параметры, поля, аннотации....".

У меня, как у новичка, возникает резонный вопрос, зачем мне эту информацию узнавать, если классы, методы, поля и т.д. я пишу сам и всё про них знаю?

Понимаю, что используется рефлексия не для своих классов и т.д., но не могу найти реальный пример, который был бы понятен новичку: в какой ситуации я столкнусь с тем, что не буду знать имя класса, метода и т.д.?

То же самое с аннотациями: "...средство, позволяющее встраивать справочную информацию в исходные файлы......". Ну встрою я её, ну а профит какой, что я в итоге с помощью этого получу? Какие плюшки для разработчика появятся при наличии аннотаций? Как они способны облегчить жизнь?

Comment: Когда это необходимо

Comment: @Владимир я применяю рефлексию когда приходят команды с клиента(браузера)(команда = имя метода) причем для облегчения читабельности для каждой веб-страницы свой файл с методами для обработки команд этой страницы. входная точка вызова методов одна. это очень удобно когда 20+ страниц по 10+ методов.

Comment: @Вадим Это замечательно, ничего против не имею.

Comment: не то имя скопировал :), сказанное для Cenzor

Comment: Вадим, спасибо.

Comment: Аннотации и рефлексия это как консервный нож к банке "консервов" вашего кода в классах, поскольку позволяет получать доступ даже к приватным полям и методам исследуемых классов :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Рефлексия и аннотации позволяют решать задачи, который в иных случаях можно было бы решить либо ручным монотонным кодированием, либо кодогенерацией.

И, конечно, когда они используются, то применяются не к конкретным классам, а с запасом, даже к тем классам, которые вы напишете в будущем. Часто их используют в библиотечном коде, который будет бродить между проектами и, соответственно, о классах тех проектов вообще не знать ничего.

Несколько конкретных примеров:

#### Аннотации Hibernate

Hibernate — это ORM, то есть библиотека для удобного отображения баз данных на объектный код. Часто в базе и в Java-коде применяются разные соглашения об именовании. Для того, чтобы Hibernate понимал, какое поле куда копировать, применяют аннотации. Для таблицы:

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
  last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
  salary     INT  default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Можно применить аннотации:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "salary")
  private int salary;  

  public Employee() {}
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId( int id ) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
    this.firstName = first_name;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
    this.lastName = last_name;
  }
  public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }
  public void setSalary( int salary ) {
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm). Кратко, что здесь происходит: в базе данных поле называется, например, `first_name`, а в Java-коде — `firstName`. Благодаря аннотациям при загрузке записей из базы в объект `Employee` библиотека самостоятельно раскидает все поля как надо.

#### Компилятор Java

Компилятор также использует аннотации для дополнительных проверок или для изменения своих настроек внутри отдельных методов. Смотрите аннотации `@Override` и `@SuppressWarnings`.

#### AndroidAnnotations

Проект http://androidannotations.org/ позволяет значительно упростить разработку кода для Android, реализовав частые задачи, и обернув их в аннотации. Это как раз хороший пример библиотечного кода, который будет работать в незнакомых проектах. Естественно, для реализации этого кода активно применяется рефлексия. Пример «до аннотаций» и «после аннотаций» приведён прямо на главной странице по ссылке выше.

#### Аспектно-ориентированное программирование

Про него много писать не буду, поскольку тема очень большая и новичку может быть не сильно нужная. Но в целом АОП как раз об этом. Например, вы можете написать свои классы, а потом озаботится проверкой прав доступа, навроде *администратор может удалять записи, а обычный пользователь — нет*.

При классическом подходе вам придётся вносить однотипные изменения в большое количество существующих классов, а потом не забывать делать это для новых. В АОП вы можете просто придумать аннотации `@Administrator`, `@User`, `@Moderator` и расставить их у нужных классов и методов. Это тоже монотонно, но всё равно гораздо проще.

#### Рефлексия без аннотаций

Рефлексия применяется ещё чаще, например, в разного рода шаблонизаторах и мапперах. Шаблонизаторы позволяют вам использовать шаблоны писем, например, как этот:

```
Здравствуйте, %username%!

Напоминаем Вам, что вы задолжали нам крупную сумму денег в размере %amount%
рублей. Мы помним!

С уважением,
  Коллекторское агентство «Солнышко»
```

Затем вы передаете шаблонизатору класс с полями `username` и `amount` и он самостоятельно сформирует текст письма. Такую задачу без рефлексии не сделать.

#### Заключение

В целом, рефлексия и аннотации позволяют избавиться от так называемого monkey coding, то есть от монотонного низкоуровнего кодирования.

Comment: Очень информативно, но мне, как новичку, всё-таки не просто это понять, так как с сопутствующими задачами пока не сталкиваюсь. Спасибо. Хотя некоторая часть вопроса прояснилась.

Answer (score 8):

1) Dependency injection framework'и на рефлексии зачастую основаны

2) Вызывать методы по имени. Скажем, есть у вас на входе имя метода, вы можете его вызвать так:

```
Method method = foo.getClass().getMethod("myMethod", null);
method.invoke(foo, null);
```

3) Тоже самое и для инстанциации классов. Мы делаем игру на Unity3d, тут, правда, C#, но суть не меняется. У нас есть куча заклинаний. Список доступных заклинаний в виде массива. Нам надо инстанциировать нужные классы по названию. Либо делать большой `switch` блок с кучей `case`, либо вызвать всего 1 метод.

4) С помощью рефлексии можно достучаться до `final` и `protected` полей класса, если необходимо. У меня была частая необходимость в этом, когда, к примеру, работал с Android. Многие поля классов из SDK были скрыты, можно было достать и изменить их только с помощью рефлексии.

P.S. но надо избегать использование рефлексии, где это возможно, так как она очень медленная по природе

Comment: по п.2: правильно ли я понял, что можно вызвать не статический метод из класса не прибегая к созданию экземпляра? Или нет?

Comment: @Cenzor `foo` - экземпляр класса.

Comment: Зачем, если я могу так foo."имя_метода"()?

Comment: @Cenzor это от кейса зависит. Если вам надо вызвать метод по его имени, то вам только `if`'ами это сделать возможно или `switch`'ем.

Comment: @Suvitruf по поводу медленности - это было очень давно. нынешняя рефлексия совсем не тормознутая. по данному поводу есть ролик с выступлением спеца, показывающего, что тормоза рефлексии  это давнишняя история